# MySQL: Join 3 tables and filter by one of them

Tags: mysql, join, blogs

I have three tables with the following columns:

```
blog:  
id | title | body

categories:
id | title

blog_categories_join: 
blog_id | category_id
```

I'm using this MySQL query to get the first 8 blog posts and join each post's respective categories:

```
SELECT b.* 
GROUP_CONCAT(c.title ORDER BY c.id ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS categories,
FROM blog b
LEFT OUTER JOIN blog_categories_join bcj ON bcj.blog_id = b.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories c ON c.id = bcj.category_id
GROUP BY b.title
ORDER BY b.date DESC LIMIT 8
```

This is working great for me. However, I'd like to get the first 8 blog posts of a specific category as well. So I've tried adding a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT b.* 
GROUP_CONCAT(c.title ORDER BY c.id ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS categories,
FROM blog b
LEFT OUTER JOIN blog_categories_join bcj ON bcj.blog_id = b.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories c ON c.id = bcj.category_id
WHERE bcj.category_id = $id 
GROUP BY b.title
ORDER BY b.date DESC LIMIT 8
```

This works in the sense that it only pulls the blogs from the specified categories, but my GROUP_CONCAT no longer contains every category the blog belongs to. It only contains the category specified in the WHERE clause.

Is it possible for me to query only posts that belong to a specified category and also return it's respective categories with the way my table structure?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just re-join categories for use of group_concat.

```
SELECT
    b.*
    GROUP_CONCAT(c2.title ORDER BY c2.id ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS categories,
FROM blog b
LEFT OUTER JOIN blog_categories_join bcj ON bcj.blog_id = b.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories c ON c.id = bcj.category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories c2 ON c2.id = bcj.category_id
WHERE c.category_id = $id
GROUP BY b.title
ORDER BY b.date
DESC LIMIT 8
```